# programming with dplyr- how to deal with quotes/enquotes

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a wrapper function that executes a database call with `dplyr`.

First create a reproducible example:

```
library("DBI")
library("dplyr")
conn = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")

df = expand.grid(indate = as.character(as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date('2017/06/06'), as.Date('2018/02/12'), by="day"))), name = c("Canada","Japan","USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

copy_to(conn, df, "lineups_country",
        temporary = FALSE, 
        indexes = list(
          "indate",
          "name"
        )
)
```

This is the code that works well without the wrapper function:

```
res = tbl(conn, table)

# filter the country
res = res %>% filter(name %in% c("Canada","Japan"))

# filter the date
res = res %>% filter(indate >= "2018-01-01")

res %>% show_query()
df2=res %>% collect()
unique(df$name);unique(df2$name)
min(df$indate);min(df2$indate)
```

Now to create the wrapper function, I have read the document https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

However things are far from clear to me, especially regarding the quotes/enquotes.

here is what I tried:

```
myFun = function(conn, table, 
                 dateCol   = "indate", 
                 startDate = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"), 
                 key       = list(name = c("Australia","Japan"))) {


  on.exit({dbDisconnect(conn)})
  res = tbl(conn, table) 

  res %>% show_query()

  # filter the country
  countryCol = names(key)
  enquo_country <- enquo(countryCol) #enquo_country <- rlang::sym(countryCol) #
  res = res %>% filter(!!enquo_country %in% key[[1]])

  res %>% show_query()

  # filter the date
  enquo_dateCol <- enquo(dateCol) #enquo_country <- rlang::sym(names(key)) #
  res = res %>% filter(!!enquo_dateCol >= as.character(startDate))

  res %>% show_query()

  return(res %>% collect())
}
```

which gives an error:

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :    'match' requires vector
>   arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `names` of 'key' and 'dateCol' are character inputs, use the `sym` from `rlang` to convert it to symbols for evaluation

```
myFun = function(conn, table, 
                 dateCol   = "indate", 
                 startDate = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"), 
                 key       = list(name = c("Australia","Japan"))) {


  on.exit({dbDisconnect(conn)})
  res = tbl(conn, table) 

  res %>%
        show_query()

  # filter the country
  countryCol = names(key)
 country <- rlang::sym(countryCol) 
  res <- res %>% 
             filter(!! (country) %in% key[[1]])

  res %>% 
         show_query()

  # filter the date
  dateCol <- rlang::sym(dateCol) 
  res <- res %>%
             filter(!! (dateCol) >= startDate)

  res %>%
       show_query()

  return(res %>% 
               collect())
 }
```

-run the function

```
df2 <- myFun(conn, 
       table = "lineups_country",    # the table name
       key = list(name = c("Canada", "Japan")), 
       dateCol = "indate",    
       startDate = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"))
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM `lineups_country`
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM `lineups_country`
#WHERE (`name` IN ('Canada', 'Japan'))
#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM (SELECT *
#FROM `lineups_country`
#WHERE (`name` IN ('Canada', 'Japan')))
#WHERE (`indate` >= '2017-12-31T18:30:00Z')

head(df2, 5)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  indate              name  
#   <chr>               <chr> 
#1 2018-01-01 05:30:00 Canada
#2 2018-01-01 05:30:00 Japan 
#3 2018-01-02 05:30:00 Canada
#4 2018-01-02 05:30:00 Japan 
#5 2018-01-03 05:30:00 Canada
```

Comment: don't we need to use `%>%   filter(UQ(country) %in% key[[1]])` to avoid `!!` to spread to the rest of the expression ?

Comment: @RockScience  I missed the `c` in country.  You can either use `UQ` or `!!`.   If you don't want to spread it `filter(!!(country) %in% key[[1]]`

Comment: where does it come from?

Comment: @RockScience  Its okay.  It would be from the deep state or something as equivalent to that in 1984  :=)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a few things:

- specify a table, not `table`, which is a function;
- use `sym` on the character vector returned by calling `names(key)` to turn it into a quosure;
- If you're going to use `enquo`, don't quote `dateCol`. If you're going to quote it, use `sym`.
- Name `startDate` consistently;
- There's no particular point in converting `startDate` to character; it's handled fine regardless.

```r
library("DBI")
library("dplyr")

conn = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")
df = expand.grid(indate = as.character(as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date('2017/06/06'), as.Date('2018/02/12'), by="day"))), 
                 name = c("Canada","Japan","USA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

copy_to(conn, df, "lineups_country",
        temporary = FALSE, 
        indexes = list("indate", "name"))

myFun = function(conn, table, 
                 dateCol   = indate, 
                 startDate = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"), 
                 key       = list(name = c("Australia","Japan"))) {
    on.exit({dbDisconnect(conn)})
    res = tbl(conn, table)     
    res %>% show_query()

    # filter the country
    enquo_country <- sym(names(key))    # use `sym` here
    res = res %>% filter(!!enquo_country %in% key[[1]])      
    res %>% show_query()

    # filter the date
    enquo_dateCol <- enquo(dateCol)
    res = res %>% filter(!!enquo_dateCol >= startDate)
    res %>% show_query()

    return(res %>% collect())
}
```

Now:

```r
df2 <- myFun(conn, 
      table = "lineups_country",    # the table name
      key = list(name = c("Canada", "Japan")), 
      dateCol = indate,    # not quoted if using `enquo`
      startDate = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"))
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM `lineups_country`
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM `lineups_country`
#> WHERE (`name` IN ('Canada', 'Japan'))
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM `lineups_country`
#> WHERE (`name` IN ('Canada', 'Japan')))
#> WHERE (`indate` >= '2018-01-01T05:00:00Z')

df2
#> # A tibble: 82 x 2
#>    indate              name  
#>    <chr>               <chr> 
#>  1 2018-01-02 19:00:00 Canada
#>  2 2018-01-02 19:00:00 Japan 
#>  3 2018-01-03 19:00:00 Canada
#>  4 2018-01-03 19:00:00 Japan 
#>  5 2018-01-04 19:00:00 Canada
#>  6 2018-01-04 19:00:00 Japan 
#>  7 2018-01-05 19:00:00 Canada
#>  8 2018-01-05 19:00:00 Japan 
#>  9 2018-01-06 19:00:00 Canada
#> 10 2018-01-06 19:00:00 Japan 
#> # ... with 72 more rows
```